# How I can transfer atrributes values from a Objects to another

Tags: java, reflection

I want tranfers attributes values from a object that came from my Entity manager to a new object.

The return Object is always null

```
 public class ReflectionUtil {

    public static Object copyAttributesFromTo(Object a, Object b) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fieldsFromFirstClass = a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] fieldsFromSecondClass = b.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field currentFieldFromTheFirstClass : fieldsFromFirstClass) {
            for (Field currentFieldFromTheSecondClass : fieldsFromSecondClass) {
                String nameOfTheFirstField = currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.getName();
                String nameOfTheSecondField = currentFieldFromTheSecondClass.getName();

                if (!Modifier.isFinal(currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.getModifiers())) {//Dispensa os Final
                    if (!currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)) {//Não sobescreve campo id
                        if (nameOfTheFirstField.equals(nameOfTheSecondField)) {
                            currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.setAccessible(true);
                            currentFieldFromTheSecondClass.setAccessible(true);
currentFieldFromTheSecondClass.get(b));
                            currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.set(a, currentFieldFromTheSecondClass.get(b));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

In the Facade call I always have to put all the attribute values to new object

```
 public void update(Profile object) {
        dao.beginTransaction();
        Profile persistedObject = dao.find(object.getId());
        persistedObject.setName(object.getName());
        dao.commitAndCloseTransaction();
    }
```

So I think to create some like that

```
public void update(Profile object) {
            dao.beginTransaction();
            Profile persistedObject = dao.find(object.getId());
            ReflectionUtil.copyAttributesFromTo(persistedObject , object);
            dao.commitAndCloseTransaction();
        }
```

Comment: Whatdo you mean by "result object"? You're returning back `a` which is the same object you pass in as the first argument to the method.

Comment: Can you show us how you are using this code and what results you expect?

Comment: In my update method I always have to put all attribute in the persistentObject. I edit the question and add the facade method

Comment: Don't post longer code examples as comment since they can't be properly formatted. Also if you have important informations you should place them in question directly.

Comment: You code still doesn't show how you are using your `ReflectionUtil.copyAttributesFromTo` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The return Object is always null

It is impossible for the return object (i.e. whatever `a` contains when you `return`) to be `null`.

It is easy to see that the code does not change the reference `a`.  There are no assignments to it in the method, so it cannot change.

The other possibility was that you called the method with a `null` value for `a`.  But if you did that, the first line of the method calls `a.getClass()` and that will throw an NPE if `a` is `null`.

**TL;DR** - it is impossible.

---

So what does this mean?

Here are the most likely explanations:

1. You are mistaken that `null` is being returned.  Perhaps the method is not being called?  Perhaps, it is not returning?
2. Maybe you have misinterpreted the evidence in some other way.  It is hard to know without seeing the code ... and the evidence.
3. Maybe you don't *mean* that the method is returning Object; i.e. I misunderstood the question.  (Your problem description is pretty unambiguous though ...)

Answer (score 1):

really miss understood why u are using  2 loop? ..   if the classes are same  . u dont need to do it .. just do it in 1 loop ..   and use  fields get for obj which is holding data .. and use set for to set .. here is the more better way .. if the same object is required u can use generics .. and same object type will be required ( request return type )

```
public static <T> T copyAttributesFromTo(T value, T dataHolder) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (value == null || dataHolder == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        final Field[] fields = value.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {

            if (!Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) {               
                field.setAccessible(true);               
                field.set(value, field.get(dataHolder));
            }
        }

        return value; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a change in the code and works to update for me

```
 public static Object copyAttributesFromTo(Object a, Object b) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fieldsFromFirstClass = a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] fieldsFromSecondClass = b.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        //JSFMessageUtil.addMsgLog(JSFMessageUtil.matricula, ReflectionUtil.class.getCanonicalName(), "ReflectionUtil: Aqui");
        for (Field currentFieldFromTheFirstClass : fieldsFromFirstClass) {
            for (Field currentFieldFromTheSecondClass : fieldsFromSecondClass) {
                Object nameOfTheFirstField = currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.getName();
                Object nameOfTheSecondField = currentFieldFromTheSecondClass.getName();

                if (!Modifier.isFinal(currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.getModifiers())) {//Dispensa os Final
                    //if (!currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)) {//Não sobescreve campo id
                        if (nameOfTheFirstField.equals(nameOfTheSecondField)) {
                            currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.setAccessible(true);
                            currentFieldFromTheSecondClass.setAccessible(true);
                            //JSFMessageUtil.addMsgLog(JSFMessageUtil.matricula, ReflectionUtil.class.getCanonicalName(), "ReflectionUtil: " + currentFieldFromTheSecondClass.get(b));
                            currentFieldFromTheFirstClass.set(a, currentFieldFromTheSecondClass.get(b));
                        }
                    //}
                }
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
```

The call

```
  public void update(Aluno a) {
        try {
            Aluno aluno = new Aluno();//(Aluno) em.find(Aluno.class, a.getId());
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            //aluno.setNome(a.getNome());
            ReflectionUtil.copyAttributesFromTo(aluno, a);
            em.merge(aluno);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getLocalizedMessage(), "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if object class  you use two for  ..  for performance u dont need to that  .. if the type of class are same types ( using same classes) check my answer .. u will understand